# Opacity=1% some times gives Win32Exception: Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: c#, .net

One of our WinForm gives below exception on Form.Show. Form's Opacity is set to 1%. We have observed that if we set Opacity to 100% error disappears. Error generaly comes when machine (not application) is running for long time without restart, generaly after 2 days.

Exception details are as below:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Not enough storage is available to process this command
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateLayered()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
MessageNot enough storage is available to process this command
StackTrace   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateLayered()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)SourceSystem.W indows.Forms
```

Comment: It seems to me that the real problem is somewhere else. If your application is running for long time, before the error occurs, then it is likely that some resources are not being disposed properly. Garbage Collector is nice but it doesn't solve all problems by itself.

Comment: Thanks ElmoVanKielmo for reply. As per observation, problem seems to be with Opacity only. When we make it 1% problem appears and when we make it 100% it diappears.

Comment: You speaking about 1% and 100%, have you tried different values? cause I'm guessing 100% doesn't do anything since it's the default...

Answer (score 9):

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Not enough storage is available to process this command

It is a very low-level Windows error, it normally indicates that the kernel memory pool is exhausted. That typically doesn't point to managed code as the source of the problem, although it is forever easy to leak window handles in a Winforms application.  Check that first, run Taskmgr.exe, switch to the Processes tab.  View + Select Columns and tick Handles, USER Objects and GDI Objects.  Observe these columns while your program is running.  In particular if USER Objects just keeps climbing then your code has a bug that may trigger this exception.  By far the most typical way to leak window handles is by using Controls.Clear() or Controls.Remove() and forgetting to call the Dispose() method on the controls you removed.  Those removed controls just accumulate on the hidden "parking window" and never get released.

If that doesn't pan out then you are looking at a problem with your machine.  With the video driver being the most likely source of the problem.  It is heavily involved in the TransparencyKey and Opacity properties, it is the video adapter that implements the effect.  Certainly the leading indicator if your program immediately bombs with this exception instead of only after running for a while.  That was not clear from the question.  Looking for a driver update is the logical next step.

Comment: Hello Hans Passat, thanks a lot for reply. 1.We have checked for USER Objects they are increasing and decreasing with form close, so that might not be the problem. 2. Problem does not occur for few initial runs when the system is just started. But it starts after few hours, and once it starts coming it comes for every run.

Comment: It could well be another process that is gobbling up kernel memory space.  Not leaving enough for your program to do what it needs to do.  You'll need to take a hard look at what is running on the machine.  SysInternals' Process Explorer is a very nice utility that provides deep insight.